# Data not displaying in blade template?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just new in Laravel 4 and currently I'm reading the documentation. I apply some of the quickstart code tutorial and here what it turns out.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/users', 'UserController@showUsers');
```

**layout.blade.php**

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Laravel Quickstart</h1>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

**users.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <p>{{ $user->name }}</p>
    @endforeach
@stop
```

**UserController.php**

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function showUsers()
    {
        $users = User::all();       
        return View::make('users.layout')->with('users', $users);
    }

}
```

When I to call directly

```
{{ $users }}
```

in **layout.blade.php** it works pretty fine but why isn't working in **users.blade.php?**

Thanks, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
return View::make('users.layout')->with('users', $users);
```

**With this**

```
return View::make('users.users')->with('users', $users);
```

Comment: I tried but got an error `throw new \InvalidArgumentException("View [$name] not found.");`

Comment: where do you put the "users.blade.php", is it under a folder?

Comment: what is the folder name?

Comment: Does your layout file inside a folder?

Comment: the `users.blade.php` and `layout.blade.php` is in the same `view` folder directory `app/views/users`

Comment: in that case, @extends('layout') should be @extends('users.layout')

Comment: I already applied the `@extends('users.layout')`. If `users.users` I got the same error but when i tried `users.layout`, no errors but data are not showned

Comment: that's because you only calling the layout file.

Comment: OMG! Its now working! How can I repay you! :) Give me your home address I will mail some bake cookies :)

Comment: tick the question as answered :)